# Generic function query

Tags: swift, generics

After reading [this](https://timekl.com/blog/2017/05/14/swift-tricks-searching-for-objects-by-type/?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=web&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_131) article by Tim Ekl - "Swift Tricks: Searching for Objects by Type", I thought "surely there's a generic function there..." so I coded this:

```
class One {}
let mixedArray:[Any] = ["One", 1, 1.0, One()]

func filterType1<T>(array: [Any]) -> [T] { // Compiles fine, but cannot be called
    return array.flatMap( { $0 as? T })
}
//let f1 = filterType1<Int>(array: mixedArray) // syntax error
//let f1 = filterType1(array: mixedArray) // generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

On reflection, it's obvious that the compiler can't infer the type of `T` at compile time if I cannot specify the type in the function name, and so to accomplish this, I need to make the seemingly spurious change:

```
func filterType2<T>(sampleType: T, array: [Any]) -> [T] {
    return array.flatMap( { $0 as? T })
}

let f2 = filterType2(sampleType: 2, array: mixedArray)// [1] as required
```

However, my question is "why does the *definition* of the function compile, when it is impossible to call?"

Comment: Just a side note, it's not an article by Natasha the Robot.

Comment: Oops, @sdasdadas, just noticed that - modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let f1: [Int] = filterType1(array: mixedArray) // [1]
```

Comment: D'oh! - write up the explanatory text, and I'll accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
let f1 = filterType1(array: mixedArray) as [Int]
```